# How to hide a column in one2many tree view dynamically?

Tags: xml, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-8

I wanted to hide a field in one2many treeview based on a boolean field,

[image: Boolean field]

If the boolean field is checked, then the field total quantity to be displayed in the following tree view..

[image: Tree view]

The tree view is of class'account.invoice.line' and the code is as follows(the boolean field):

```
class account_invoice_line(models.Model):
    _name = "account.invoice.line"
    _description = "Invoice Line"
    _order = "invoice_id,sequence,id"

    name = fields.Text(string='Description')
    tot_qty_bool = fields.Boolean(string='Total Quantity', default=False)
    tot_qty = fields.Float(string='Total Quantity')
    origin = fields.Char(string='Source Document',
        help="Reference of the document that produced this invoice.")
    sequence = fields.Integer(string='Sequence', default=10,
        help="Gives the sequence of this line when displaying the 
invoice.")
    invoice_id = fields.Many2one('account.invoice', string='Invoice 
Reference',
        ondelete='cascade', index=True)
    uos_id = fields.Many2one('product.uom', string='Unit of Measure',
        ondelete='set null', index=True)
    product_id = fields.Many2one('product.product', string='Product',
        ondelete='set null', index=True)
    account_id = fields.Many2one('account.account', string='Account',
        domain=[('type', 'not in', ['view', 'closed'])],
        default=_default_account,
        help="The income or expense account related to the selected 
product.")
    price_unit = fields.Float(string='Unit Price', required=True,
        digits= dp.get_precision('Product Price'),
        default=_default_price_unit)
    price_subtotal = fields.Float(string='Amount', digits= 
dp.get_precision('Account'),
        store=True, readonly=True, compute='_compute_price')
    quantity = fields.Float(string='Actual Quantity', digits= 
dp.get_precision('Product Unit of Measure'),
        required=True, default=1)
    discount = fields.Float(string='Discount (%)', digits= 
dp.get_precision('Discount'),
        default=0.0)
    invoice_line_tax_id = fields.Many2many('account.tax',
        'account_invoice_line_tax', 'invoice_line_id', 'tax_id',
        string='Taxes', domain=[('parent_id', '=', False)])
    account_analytic_id = fields.Many2one('account.analytic.account',
        string='Analytic Account')
    company_id = fields.Many2one('res.company', string='Company',
        related='invoice_id.company_id', store=True, readonly=True)
    partner_id = fields.Many2one('res.partner', string='Partner',
        related='invoice_id.partner_id', store=True, readonly=True)
```

and the code part I had tried something like this in fields_view_get(which was not successful)

```
def fields_view_get(self, view_id=None, view_type='form', 
toolbar=False, submenu=False):
        res = super(account_invoice_line, self).fields_view_get(
            view_id=view_id, view_type=view_type, toolbar=toolbar, 
submenu=submenu)
        if self._context.get('tot_qty_bool'):
            doc1 = etree.XML(res['arch'])
            for node in doc.xpath("//field[@name='tot_qty']"):
                if self._context['tot_qty_bool'] in ('False'):
                    node.set('invisible', '1')
                else:
                    node.set('invisible', '0')
            res['arch'] = etree.tostring(doc)
        return res
```

Please guide me on the correct way of doing this or let me know if there is any other alternative correct way of achieving the same. Would be really a great help.

Comment: try to add an attribute `attrs="{'invisible': [('tot_qty_bool', '=', 0)]}" in the field's tag in XML

Comment: macdelacruz, still its not working. anything to be passed in context ?

Comment: To invisible field in tree view atrrs won't work. you can only set readonly and required in tree view if the tree view is editabl but you can not use invisible in attrs for treeview.

Comment: Yes, I agree wth you Emipro Technologies, but is this case possible in any other way? hiding a column in a one2many tree view based on boolean field value ?

Comment: Actually it is possible with attrs and invisible. Tested on runbot Odoo V8.

Answer (score 3):

`fields_view_get` is called when odoo is rendering a view of the model and only during the initial rendering.So what you try to do can only be done when an `account.invoice.line` view is rendered.

Try to inherit `invoice_form` view and use `attrs` to hide `tot_qty` field. *(you need to add `tot_qty_bool` field inside the tree view)*.

```
<record id="invoice_form_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
  <field name="name">invoice.form.inherit</field>
  <field name="model">account.invoice</field>
  <field name="inherit_id" ref="account.invoice_form"/>
  <field name="arch" type="xml">
      <xpath expr="//tree/field[@name='name']" position="after">
            <field name='tot_qty_bool' invisible="True"/> 
            <field name='tot_qty' attrs="{'invisible':[('tot_qty_bool', '=', False)]}"/>
        </xpath>

  </field>
</record>
```

Comment: it will hide the content of the particular column. but how to hide the column label itself.

Comment: @ShravyaShetty There would be a problem if some of the products fulfill the `attr-domain` and some do not.So it is not possible to hide a column foir certain products

Answer (score 1):

As @macdelacruz already has mentioned in a comment, use `attrs` and `invisible` in your tree view definition.

I've tested an similar example on Odoo V8 runbot.

From origin timesheet form view:

```xml
<field name="name" />
```

Just change it to:

```xml
<field name="name" attrs="{'invisible': [('unit_amount','=',0)]}"/>
```

Save it, reload and try to play around with it. It's working.